# Can I charge a 4th gen iPod touch with the Galaxy tab's charger?

Tags: ipod-touch, charging

Can I charge a fourth generation iPod touch with Samsung Galaxy Tab's charger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plug a standard Apple 30pin USB Charging cable into the Galaxy Tab charger and it will work fine.  Both the Apple and Samsung chargers deliver 5v output (although the Samsung one delivers a higher current).  It is perfectly safe to use.

Comment: no.. i meant the charger, not the USB connector

Comment: ah I see.  I amended answer.

Answer (score -2):

NO I tried it, it didn't work.